# Quick OSM Save As Shapefile error "Can't create field"

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, error, save

I have used the quick osm plugin to import the rivers in Germany.

[image]

I want to save the vector layer as a shapefile so I right click on the layer and go to save as... and save it as a shapefile layer

[image]

Once I click okay this error message appears

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post error messages in the body of the question as ASCII text. This allows others to search on your question.

Comment: Why was this question put on hold? It's clearly a GIS-specific question, not a general IT question. And I don't see any reason why other users won't encounter a similar issue when they try to save a layer with a longer name than the shapefile format allows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message mentions there is a problem with creating a field called "service_times"

Exclude this field from the export by un-ticking the box next to its name under the heading `Select fields to export and their export options`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The DBF format of the shapefile attribute table generally forces to cut the filed names after 10 characters. If you have fields `service_time` and `service_times`, this will create the error you got.

Changing the file type from shapefile to sqlite, geopackage or geojson solves your problem, and will preserve the original field names from OSM.